# Add new rows onto Datagridview without clearing existing rows in VbNet

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I would like to load data into a datagrid by running a query in loop and adding the result to the previously loaded rows, but at each query cycle the rows are deleted and replaced with new data. Your help is appreciated.
Here is my code in VbNet

```
Dim selectSql = "SELECT id,articolo,quantità  FROM 
                [Magazzino] WHERE val(idcarico) = ('" & rMag & "')"

        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectSql, conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "magazzino")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("magazzino")
        Dim row As DataRow
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row In dt.Rows
                Me.DGDettaglioMerci.Rows.Add(row("id"), row("articolo"), 
                row("quantità"))
            Next row
        End If
```

Comment: There is nothing in that code that is going to remove any rows from the grid. If that's happening then it's because you're doing it elsewhere. That said, you're doing it all wrong anyway. Don't loop through the `DataTable` and then copy data from it to the grid. Just bind the `DataTable` to the grid. If you then want to retrieve new data then do that, into the same `DataTable`. The grid is bound to the `DataTable` so it will just show whatever the `DataTable` contains at all times. Also, don't create a `DataSet` that you don't need. Just create a `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks @John, i will try to watch better the flow to see if it happens in other sub. As for the use of binding, I understand the concept, but I don't understand how to retrieve new data using the same datatable, maybe someone can direct me to some examples

Comment: @Jayelef, Have a read up on the Merge() datatable method.  Query results go into a temp DataTable, then you can merge with the actual datatable you're displaying